# What triggers enemies double or triple special moves on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

Sometimes enemies (NPC) have a full special bar, 3 full bars ready to go. But instead of using them all at once, they attack using a double special move and keep one as reserve.

What determines if enemies special attacks will be double or triple? and most important, is there a way to avoid them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer AI will not use a Level 3 ability in any quests. They can only use a Level 3 ability in an arena. (or during alliance quest)

[edit] since the writing of this answer, the Contest has evolved, and some quests have special nodes which allow a Level 3. Those cases are, however, quite clear as the nodes are very visible.  As a general rule, it still stands that AI doesn't use Level 3 abilities during quests ... baring special nodes ;) [/edit]

Comment: I have also noticed that all minions in arenas do not use L3 special attacks, like androids for example. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, that's true, drones don't have a L3 in any case ... :)

Comment: Some quests have enemies with L3 attacks, so can you replace "any" with "most"?