# How does power sting work with special power lvl 3 on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I play a lot with Yellow Jacket and I really like to use power sting.

When an enemy has power sting status and he tries to cast a special attack, he gets punished by causing damage to himself. However when he is about to cast a SP3 (level 3 special power, meaning when he has a full special bar) sometimes the power sting hits before the special move and sometimes after it.

How do I know if power sting will hit my opponent before or after he casts a SP3? Does it depend on the targeted champion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of SP1 and SP2 the damage is received **before** the special. However it is received **after** the special animation for SP3.

What might cause the confusion is the fact that sometimes the enemy will have a special bar full (level 3) but will launch a SP2. Refer to [What triggers enemies double or triple special moves on Marvel Contest of the Champions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232357/what-triggers-enemies-double-or-triple-special-moves-on-marvel-contest-of-the-ch) to figure out which SP was being used.

It also means that if you get hit by Biosting and you have a SP1 or SP2 bar loaded you should pay attention to your health before using the special because you might die from the damage caused by power sting. However if you have SP3 loaded and you are 100% sure that your special will kill your opponent then you should use your special thus killing your target before receiving the damage from biosting.